# Python 2 - How to fix TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, save

When i try to get my save it gives me this error i've been searching up other peoples answers but i cant find anything to solve my problem.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\game.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open('objs.pickle', "latin1", "r") as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'r')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How can i fix this? This is my whole text game below

```
################################################################################
# python C:\Users\user\Downloads\game.py                                       #   
#                                                                              #
#                                                                              #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################
import datetime
import time
from random import randint
import pickle
user_input = input ("Would you like to continue your save? (1=Yes) (2=No)")
if int(user_input) == 1:
    with open('objs.pickle', "latin1", "r") as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'r')
        money = pickle.load(f)
else:
    start = 1
    timer2 = 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timer = ('{0}{1}'.format(now.hour, now.minute))
    hunger = 10
    thirst = 10
    energy = 10
    drinks = 0
    foods = 0
    money = 0
    plan = 150
    drink = 1
    food = 1.25
    wanted = 0
    gun = 0

print ("Chapter 1")
print ("The Big City")
time.sleep(1)
print ("You lost your brother recently and are very sad about it but something about his death bugs you the doctors told you that he died of a heart attack but you dont belive this and think he was murdered he used to write in a diary and he would keep it with him whenever he went to Mcdonalds You decide to move to the Big City")
def Eat():
    try:
        global money, plan, drink, food, drinks, foods, wanted, gun
        print (" ")
        print (" Hello welcome to Mcdonald's how may I help you")
        print ("\r Type 1 for food")
        print ("\r Type 2 for drinks")
        print ("\r Type 3 for money")
        user_input = input ("\r Type 4 to walk over to the shady guy")
        print (" ")
        if int(user_input) == 1:
            print (" ")
            print (" We have Hamburgers, fries, and cancer")
            print ("\r Type 1 for hamburgers")
            print ("\r Type 2 for fries")
            user_input = input ("\r Type 3 cancer")
            print (" ")
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                print (" ")
                print (" That will cost you $1.25")
                print ("\r Type 1 to pay")
                user_input = input ("Type 2 to steal")
                print (" ")
                if int(user_input) == 1:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("Thank you for comming")
                    money = float(money) - float(food)
                    print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
                    print (" ")
                foods = float(foods) + (1)
                if int(user_input) == 2:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("HEY COME BACK AND PAY!")
                    wanted = float(wanted) + (1) 
                    print('Your wanted level is now {0}'.format(wanted))
                    print (" ")
            elif int(user_input) == 2:
                print (" ")
                print ("Potato!")
                print (" ")
            elif int(user_input) == 3:
                print (" ")
                print ("Sorry we are out of cancer")
                print (" ")
        elif int(user_input) == 2:
            print (" ")
            print ("We have Coke, and Pepsi")
            print ("Type 1 for Coke")
            user_input = input ("Type 2 for Pepsi")
            print (" ")
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                print (" ")
                print ("COKE SUCKS NO DRINKS FOR YOU!!!!!")
                print (" ")
            elif int(user_input) == 2:
                print (" ")
                print ("Nice I LOVE Pepsi Coke sucks that will cost you $1.00")
                print ("Type 1 to pay")
                user_input = input ("Type 2 to steal")
                print (" ")
                if int(user_input) == 1:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("Thank you for comming")
                    print (" ")
                    money = float(money) - float(drink)
                    print (" ")
                    print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
                    print (" ")
                elif int(user_input) == 2:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("HEY COME BACK AND PAY!")
                    wanted = float(wanted) + (1) 
                    print('Your wanted level is now {0}'.format(wanted))
                    print (" ")
                drinks = float(drinks) + (1)
        elif int(user_input) == 3:
            print (" ")
            print ("So heres the plan you take the register ill destract the others.")
            user_input = input ("Type 1 to do the plan")
            print (" ")
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                plan = (randint(1,20))
                money = float(money) + float(plan)
                print (" ")
                print('You got {0} Dollars for doing the plan'.format(plan))
                print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
                wanted = float(wanted) + (1) 
                print('Your wanted level is now {0}'.format(wanted))
                print (" ")
        elif int(user_input) == 4:
            print (" ")
            print ("Heres the deal I can sell you a Gun or Hack the wanted list.")
            print ("Type 1 to buy a gun for 500$")
            user_input = input ("Type 2 to hack for 100$")
            print (" ")
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                if money > 500:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("Here take it now run off before the cops come")
                    print (" ")
                    gun = 1
                    money = float(money) - (500)
            if int(user_input) == 2:
                if money > 100:
                    print (" ")
                    print ("Here im done now run off before the cops come")
                    print (" ")
                    wanted = 0
                    money = float(money) - (100)

        print (" ")        
        print ("Type 1 to order")
        user_input = input ("Type 2 for main menu")
        print (" ")
        if int(user_input) == 1 and (money) > 1:
            Eat()
        elif int(user_input) == 2:
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    except ValueError:
        Eat()


def work():
    global gain
    global money
    global energy
    gain = 1
    from random import randint
    work1 = (randint(1,20))
    hours = (randint(1,8))
    answer = float(work1) * float(hours)
    print (" ")
    print('Bob worked {0} hours and got {1} dollars per hour '.format(hours,work1))
    work2 = input('How much money did bob make')
    print (" ")
    if int(work2) == int(answer):
        print (" ")
        print ("you gained 1 Dollars")
        money = float(money) + float(gain)
        print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
        print("Type 1 to work again") 
        user_input = input ("Type 2 to go to main menu")
        print (" ")
        energy = float(energy) - float(gain)
        if int(user_input) == 1:
            work()
        if int(user_input) == 2:
            menu()
    else:
        print (" ")
        print ("You lost 1 Dollar")
        if money > 0:
            money = float(money) - float(gain)
            print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
            print("Type 1 to work again") 
            user_input = input ("Type 2 to go to main menu")
            print (" ")
            energy = float(energy) - float(gain)
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                work()
            if int(user_input) == 2:
                menu()
        else:
            print (" ")
            print('You now have {0} Dollars '.format(money))
            print("Type 1 to work again") 
            user_input = input ("Type 2 to go to main menu")
            print (" ")
            energy = float(energy) - float(gain)
            if int(user_input) == 1:
                work()
            if int(user_input) == 2:
                menu()


def items():
    global energy
    global money
    global hunger
    global thirst
    global foods
    global drinks
    global gun
    print (" ")
    print('You have a wallet (${0})  '.format(money))
    if int(gun) > 0:
        print('You have a gun')
    if int(foods) > 0: 
        print('You have {0} hamburgers type 1 to eat hamburger'.format(foods))
    if int(drinks) > 0:
        print('You have {0} Pepsi type 2 to drink Pepsi'.format(drinks))
    user_input = input('Type 3 to go to main menu')
    if int(user_input) == 1 and int(foods) > 0:
        hunger = float(hunger) + (3)
        energy = float(energy) + (3)
        foods = float(foods) - (1)
    if int(user_input) == 2 and int(drinks) > 0:
        thirst = float(thirst) + (2)
        energy = float(energy) + (1)
        drinks = float(drinks) - (1)
    if int(user_input) == 3:
        menu()
    print (" ")
    menu()
def dead():
    input("gg dude you ded")

def menu():
    global wanted
    global now
    global timer
    global hunger
    global thirst
    global money
    global gun
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timer2 = ('{0}{1}'.format(now.hour, now.minute))
    if (0) > (hunger) or (0) > (thirst):
        dead()
    if (wanted) > (9):
        if gun == 1:
            wanted = 9
            print (" ")
            print ("You shot the cops but you are not off their radar")
            print (" ")
        else:
            money = float(thirst) - float(money) * .5
            wanted = 0
            print (" ")
            print ("You got caught by the cops")
            print (" ")
    if (timer2) > (timer):
        thirst = float(thirst) - (1)
        hunger = float(hunger) - (1)
        timer = float(timer) + (1)
        timer = ('{0}{1}'.format(now.hour, now.minute))
        menu()
    print (" ")
    print ("Type 1 to Work")
    print ("Type 2 to go to Mcdonalds")
    print ("Type 3 to see your inventory")
    print('You have {0} / 10 hunger'.format(hunger))
    print('You have {0} / 10 thirst'.format(thirst))
    print('You have {0} / 10 energy'.format(energy))
    print('You have {0} / 10 wanted'.format(wanted))
    user_input = input('You have {0} dollars '.format(money))
    print (" ")
    if int(user_input) == 1:
        work()
    elif int(user_input) == 2 and (money) > 1:
        Eat()
    elif int(user_input) == 3:
        items()
    elif int(user_input) == 795535:
        money = float(money) + (1000)
        menu()
    elif int(user_input) == 4:
        with open('objs.pickle', 'ab') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'wb')
            pickle.dump([money], f)

    else:
        print (" ")
        print ("You need more money")
        print (" ")
        menu()
menu()
```

Comment: First of all, don't put your entire code as ask for getting it solved. Figure out exactly what's the issue you're having and then post parts of the code, or a simple piece of code which can recreate your issue.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know.

Comment: Thats called [mcve] where "minimal" means minimum code required to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: Anyway, figured out your issue. Basically have to give the encoding as an argument to the open() function. Possibly like `encoding='latin1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saved your file with

```
open('objs.pickle', 'ab') as f
```

Then, you should open your file like

```
open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f
```

Comment: But now it gives me this

Comment: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You saved your file as binary. Then you should also open your file as binary mode. try "rb" instead of "r"

Comment: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: Im kinda new to python so im not experienced with errors

Comment: Then try `open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f`. I thought the encoding was necessary for some reason.

Comment: Wow thanks it worked I tried that at the start but it didnt work for some reason but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here:

```
with open('objs.pickle', "latin1", "r") as f
```

Here are the arguments [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) takes:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
         errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

In your case:

```
open('objs.pickle', "latin1", "r")

file = 'objs.pickle'
mode = "latin1"
buffering = "r"
```

You should do it like so:

```
open('objs.pickle', 'r', encoding="latin1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Open:
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

Use this : encoding='UTF-8'

```
open('objs.pickle','r',encoding='latin1')
```